# How to pass parameters of Ajax URL in Django?

Tags: python, django, ajax

I used Ajax to add items to wishlist:

```
<a href="{% url 'listing:wishlist' list.slug %}" id="wishlistbtn" data-slug='{{ list.slug }}'>Add to
wishlist</a>
```

the url looks like:

```
path('wishlist/<slug:title_slug>/', wishlist, name='wishlist'),
```

but I don't know how to pass `list.slug` or `title_slug` in above url using Ajax:

```
$(document).on('click', '#wishlistbtn', function (e) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "{% url 'listing:wishlist' %}",

        data: {
            title_slug: e.target.getAttribute('data-slug')
        },

        success: function (response) {
            alert('added to wishlist')
        }
    })
})
```

my above stated solution didn't work? Please help me with this. Thank you.

edit: View added

```
def wishlist(request):
    slug = request.GET.get('title_slug')
    obj = get_object_or_404(Listing, slug=slug)
    profile = Profile.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).first()
    profile.wishlist.add(obj)

    return HttpResponse('true')
```

Answer (score 0):

is this your solution to pass the `data-slug` ?

```
$(document).on('click', '#wishlistbtn', function (e) {
            let el = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "{% url 'listing:wishlist' %}",
        
                data: {
                    title_slug: el.attr("data-slug"),
                },
        
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('added to wishlist')
                }
            })
        })
```

use this path -

```
path('wishlist', wishlist, name='wishlist'),
```

in your views to get slug use - `request.GET.get("title_slug")`

Comment: still getting error: `Reverse for 'wishlist' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['wishlist\\/(?P<title_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/$']`

Comment: @BasirPayenda if you are passing slug in `GET` then no need of `title_slug` in url parameter

Comment: if I remove `title_slug` from url then how do I identify which object has to be added to wishlist, if I didn't understand please edit your answer and let me know what to do. thank you

Comment: @BasirPayenda see last line - `request.GET.get("title_slug")`

Comment: I am getting an error `Page not found (404)`. please take a look to updated question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want to do but I had similar situation, I will share my code with you hopefully it helps you

HTML

```
 <div class="btn-wrapper">
              <p id="loadMore_articles" data-total="{{total_data}}" data-limit="3" data-slug="{{author.id}}" class="btn-default transparent-btn-2 .">load articles <i class=" load-more-icon"></i></p>
          </div>
```

JQuery/JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#loadMore_articles").on('click', function () {
        var _currentarticles = $(".article-box").length;
        var _limit = $(this).attr('data-limit');
        var _total = $(this).attr('data-total');
        var _slug = $(this).attr('data-slug');
        // Start Ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: 'author/articles/load-more-articles',
            data: {
                slug: _slug,
                limit: _limit,
                offset: _currentarticles
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#loadMore_articles").attr('disabled', true);
                $("#loadMore_articles").html('');
                $(".load-more-icon").addClass('fa-spin');
               
                $("#loadMore_articles").addClass("button--loading");
               

              
            },
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res.articles);
                $("#articles").append(res.articles);
                $("#loadMore_articles").attr('disabled', false);

                $(".load-more-icon").removeClass('fa-spin');
                $("#loadMore_articles").html('Load Articles');
                $("#loadMore_articles").removeClass("button--loading");

                

                if (res.articles == '') {
                    $("#loadMore_articles").remove();
                }
            }
        });
        // End
    });
});
```

**views.py**

```
def author_ajax_articles(request):
    author = int(request.GET['slug'])
    offset=int(request.GET['offset'])
    limit=int(request.GET['limit'])
    data=News.objects.filter(Q(author=author)&Q(is_live=True))[offset:offset+limit]
    t=render_to_string('author/ajax/article.html',{'articles':data})
    return JsonResponse({'articles':t})
```

forgive my bad codes... I am still learning `clean code` but I hope this helps you in your quest